# Return a sentence with numerical values

Tags: functions

I have the following function:

```
example[a_, b_] := 
  Module[{c},
    c = a + b;
    Return["The solution is c"]
  ]
```

I would like to know how to return that sentence but with the actual value of c. For example, if I write `example[x, x+1]`, I want to obtain `"The solution is 2x+1"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Old versions**:

Use `StringForm[]`:

```
example[a_, b_] := Module[{c = a + b},
         ToString[StringForm["The solution is ``", c]]]

example[x, x + 1]
   "The solution is 1 + 2 x"
```

**New versions**:

Use `StringTemplate[]`:

```
example[a_, b_] := Module[{c = a + b},
        StringTemplate["The solution is `sol`"] @
        <|"sol" -> ToString[c, StandardForm]|>]

example[x, x + 1]
   "The solution is 1 + 2 x"
```

(The actual output contains `RowBox` objects within the string.)

Answer (score 2):

Apart from ``` StringForm["The solution is ``", c] ```, another solution is using `StringJoin[](<>)` directly.

```
example[a_, b_] := 
  Module[{c}, c = a + b;
   "The solution is " <> ToString[c]
  ]
```

Or

```
example[a_, b_] := "The solution is " <> ToString[a + b]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the format separate form the function (could be useful in situations where you have many functions like `example` you want to format like this.

Define an UpValue `solution` that uses TextString

```
solution /: TextString[solution[s_]] := 
 "The solution is " <> ToString[s // TraditionalForm]
```

Now using this definition for `example`:

```
example[a_, b_] := Module[{c}, c = a + b]

TextString[solution@example[x, x + 1]]
(* "The solution is 2 x + 1" *)
```

With a new `example2` we can use `solution` again:

```
example2[a_, b_] := 
 Module[{c}, c = Integrate[Sin[a x + b], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]]

TextString[solution@example2[a, b]]

(* "The solution is \!\(\*FormBox[FractionBox[\(2\\\ \
    \(sin(π\\\ a)\)\\\ \(sin(π\\\ a + b)\)\), \(a\)],
    TraditionalForm]\)" *)
```